# Rename grouper in regroup

Tags: django, templates

I have read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup), but I have one more question: how I can rename country.grouper in the template? I 'group' week days - week_days.grouper, its like 1, 2, 3 etc. But I want change it in the template - Sunday, Monday etc. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) should help you out here. It has to be put into a file e.g. `my_custom_filters.py` in your app in a folder called templatetags:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

def get_weekday(value):
    """returns the weekday for the given number - 0 indexed"""
    wd_list = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
    return wd_list[int(value)]
```

This custom filter will be used like this:

```
{% load my_custom_filters %}

{% regroup day by weekdays as weekday_list %}

<ul>
{% for day in weekday_list %}
    <li>{{ day.grouper|get_weekday }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in day.list %}
          <li>{{ item.name }}: {{ item.population }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If you are using a date object could use the build-in [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date) template tag to convert a date to the corresponding weekday:

```
{% regroup day by weekdays as weekday_list %}

<ul>
{% for day in weekday_list %}
    <li>{{ day.grouper|date:"w" }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in day.list %}
          <li>{{ item.name }}: {{ item.population }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: it very strange - it doesnt work. I test it on day.grouper values = 1, 2, 5

Comment: The issue is probably that the date filter needs a date object as an input and does not work on strings. So you might try to create your list with a datetime object instead of a string representing the day. Or write your own custom template filter. Will update my answer to include it.

Comment: in def get_weekday(value, arg) - I delete 'arg' and it works. Thanks.